# Calling a function pointer whose assigned function has less arguments then the pointer type

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, calling-convention

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*test_func_t) (int, int, int);

int print_integer (int a)
{
    std::cout << "num: " << a << "\n";
    return a;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    test_func_t func = (test_func_t) &print_integer;
    std::cout << "calling with 3 parameters func(5,7,9)\n";
    func(5,7,9);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, a type (test_func_t) is defined as a function with 3 int arguments. A function pointer (func) is assigned with a pointer to "print_integer", which receives only 1 argument, and the function pointer is then called with 3 arguments (5, 7, 9).

This code works and produces "num: 5" output.

gdb disas output (Intel syntax)

```
disas main
...
   0x080486cb <+9>:     mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x804867d
...
   0x080486e0 <+37>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],0x9
   0x080486e8 <+45>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x7
   0x080486f0 <+53>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x5
   0x080486f7 <+60>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
   0x080486fb <+64>:    call   eax

disas print_integer
   ...
   0x08048683 <+6>:     mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x8048830
   0x0804868b <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8049ae0
   0x08048692 <+21>:    call   0x8048530 <std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)@plt>
   0x08048697 <+26>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x0804869a <+29>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
   0x0804869e <+33>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x080486a1 <+36>:    call   0x80484d0 <std::ostream::operator<<(int)@plt>
```

As you can see, the rest of the arguments ([ebp+0x12] and [ebp+0x16]) are simply not used.

My questions:

1. This seems to work on Linux x86 with __cdecl calling convention. Is it safe on other architectures and calling conventions as well?
2. Does any C/C++ standard allows/defines the result of assigning a function pointer from a function that expects fewer arguments?

Example of such use: node.js's [NODE_MODULE](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12.7/src/node.h#L388-L427) registers a function whose [type](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12.7/src/node.h#L338-L341) has 3 arguments [exports, module, priv]. It is [called with those 3](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12.7/src/node.cc#L2217-L2218) but formal examples show registering of a function with [1](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world) or [2](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_callbacks) arguments.

Comment: No and No. It is undefined behavior. And it is not safe anywhere.

Comment: It is not well-defined and, in general, a bad idea and not safe.  Although with that said, it used to be fairly common practice, and under the calling conventions where it works, it works just fine.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "Not safe" - I totally accept that. Is there an example which causes this type of call to "break" things? (besides the obviously wrong use and abuse)

Comment: @The-Q Such an example might be the next version of `gcc` . It doesn't have to happen *currently* to not be safe.

Comment: I did see this use in node.js (as mentioned in the original question) and I have no intention to implement anything using this. After understanding it might not be safe, I wonder if an actual case which this might break something can be currently found. Thanks @EugeneSh. !

Comment: Btw, if you can link to the code you are mention in the question, it would be interesting to take a look at it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. links added.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - node.js example is C++, but both are interesting to me.

Comment: @The-Q: Be that as it may, pick one.

Answer (score 12):

Quoting from the C++11 standard *expr.reinterpret.cast 6*:

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling
>   a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that **is not the same as the type used in the definition**
>   of the function is **undefined**.

So, I'd say that it is **not** safe in general. It is undefined behaviour. That said, I don't know how other implementation of C++ behave in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Thus will work on all platforms that use the __cdecl calling convention. This calling convention pushes the arguments right-to-left onto the stack and then calls the function. A function requiring less parameters than pushed will thus simply not access the parameters more to the right, which were pushed earlier and are higher on the stack.

```
// func(5,7,9);
push 9
push 7
push 5
call func
---> func:
     push bp
     mov bp, sp
     mov ax, [bp+8]  ; get 5

// stack:
9
7
5                     [bp+8]
<return address>      [bp+4]
<value of old bp>        ^
    new bp: -------------+
```

Comment: It _might_ work for `__cdecl` calls ... an implementation could add runtime instrumentation to check for such undefined behaviour and abort at runtime, or an optimiser could decide that what you tried to do is undefined and remove the call entirely. That's the joy of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jonathan-wakely, no C implementation is allowed to do that. The C language allows it and it is a tool at the disposition of the programmer. It is further required for backward compatibility with C versions that did not use prototypes. The quote of Paolo further says the _effect_ is undefined, meaning the standard prescribes no behavior and leaves it up to the programmer, which is correct. The standard, nor smart ass implementations should mingle with my programming, especially when I known damn well what I am doing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a program with `#include <iostream>` is not C though. Maybe qualify your answer by saying the rules are different for C and C++.

Comment: And undefined behaviour absolutely does not mean it's left up to the programmer. That would suggest when you break the rules of the language you get to decide the new rules and clearly that isn't true. If you dereference an uninitialized pointer you don't get to decide what happens!