# C++ - Can the following code cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

take a look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

void Func1(int x)
{
    std::cout << "I'm function 1: " << x << std::endl;
}

void Func2(int x, const char* str)
{
    std::cout << "I'm function 2: (this is arg1: " << x << " - args2: " << str << ")" << std::endl;
}

uintptr_t GetProcAddress(const char* _str)
{
    if (strcmp(_str, "func1") == 0)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(Func1);
    }
    else
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(Func2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    typedef void(*PROCADDR)(int, const char*);
    PROCADDR ext_addr = nullptr;
    ext_addr = (PROCADDR)GetProcAddress((const char*)"func1");

    //call the function
    ext_addr(10, "arg");


    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

We are basically calling Func1 with 2 arguments and can switch to call Func2 with the same args and everything works as intended.

Of course the address of both the arguments are always pushed on to the stack even though the second one is never used by the function itself.

Now I understand that the above code should never be used in production-code but my main question is, can the above code cause UB or is the code always expected to act like that?

Best regards
xx

Comment: Isn't an inline string already `const char*`? Also what are you trying to do here? This seems like a really bad idea from top to bottom. Calling a function that takes two arguments with one argument *might* work, but that's the most trivial case and I would't count on it working in a general sense. Compiler optimizations could easily trash this, or worse, not want to touch it because they can't anticipate what you're doing.

Comment: Exactly covered by [Calling a function pointer whose assigned function has less arguments then the pointer type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479552/calling-a-function-pointer-whose-assigned-function-has-less-arguments-then-the-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's undefined behavior. From [expr.reinterpret.cast]:

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling
>   a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined.

Comment: Thank you mate, I though it might be UB but didn't find anything about it.

Comment: There are some systems (Windows, for example) where this will lead to a crash, so it's not a purely theoretical issue.