# Convert between std::function with different signatures (T* arg to void* arg)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14, std-function

Is there a way to convert a `std::function` that has to a `T*` argument to similar one that has a `void*` argument? It seems possible since the calls should be compatible at the binary level.

As an example, how can I make this work without turning `Producer` into a template or losing type safety?

```
#include <functional>

struct Producer {
    // produces an int from a callable and an address
    template<class Src>
    Producer(Src& src, std::function<int (Src*)> f)
      : arg_(&src),
        f_(f)
    {}

    int operator()() {
        return f_(arg_);
    }

    // type erasure through void* but still type safe since ctor
    // checks that *arg_ and f are consistent
    void* arg_;
    std::function<int (void*)> f_;
};

int func1(char* c) {
    return *c;
}

int func2(int* i) {
    return *i;
}


int try_it() {
    char c = 'a';
    char i = 5;
    // we want to make these work
    Producer p1(c, func1);
    Producer p2(i, func2);
    // but we still want this to fail to compile
    // Producer p3(c, func2);
    return p1() + p2();
}
```

**Edit**: [Solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ae305491329576a) with definite UDB but correct behavior. :-/

Comment: `It seems possible since the calls should be compatible at the binary level.` While both pointers are (probably) not different in memory, it's definitely UB in some way. What should the called function do with a not-T passed where a T is expected? ... I don't see why you're worried about losing type safety when you intend to lose it.

Comment: Related: [Calling a function pointer whose assigned has different type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31479828/2508150)

Comment: @deviantfan Are you sure about UDB? As long as the casts to and from `void*` have the right type I think it's legit. The ctor prevents getting a non-T but if it didn't *then* it would be UDB. I don't see why you say this isn't type safe.

Comment: I would use bind to make the function calls have the same signature.  This way, Producer is just calling a function objects with no additional arguments.

Comment: @AnonMail Is there a way to do that without the user of `Producer` being the one to do so? Oh and in the real situation where this came up I had two functions that used the `void*`.

Comment: @Praxeolitic While the handling in the function may be ok, how do you intend to convert the function objects in the first place? Casting addresses to the other type here is definitely UB, and just passing the one thing as constructor parameter of the other won't compile here (or does it for you?)

Comment: @Praxeolitic Probably with perhaps a member template function.  But I'm not that advanced.  What I would do is first start out with overloaded constructors for the different types you want to use as input and then later possibly reduce the code with a template member function.

Comment: @deviantfan Ha, nope, definitely doesn't compile. I don't quite understand your comment but I think the `std::function` itself handles erasing the actual function object type. Here we just need one object address conversion which doesn't change how the `std::function` invokes the callable (however that may be).

Comment: I assume you mean "int i" instead of "char i" as you have written in your linked Solution. I tried to make an edit but it was rejected because apparently I should have commented instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just **not** take the argument as a `std::function`, and then you won't have to worry about it. Take any type `F`, as long as you can call it with a `Src*` and it returns something that can be converted to `int`. Start with a SFINAE-friendly `std::result_of_t` (borrowed shamelessly from Yakk):

```
template<class F, class...Args>
using invoke_result = decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

And use that to SFINAE your constructor:

```
template<class Src,
         class F,
         class = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible<invoke_result<F, Src*>, int>::value
         >>
Producer(Src& src, F f)
    : arg_(&src)
    , f_([f = std::move(f)](void* arg){
        return f(static_cast<Src*>(arg));  
    })
{ }
```

No UB there. This also correctly rejects your `p3` case. Furthermore, you don't even need `arg_` unless you're using it for some other reason. Store `f_` as:

```
std::function<int ()> f_;
```

and stick the `Src` in it:

```
template<class Src,
         class F,
         class = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible<invoke_result<F, Src*>, int>::value
         >>
Producer(Src& src, F f)
    : f_([&src, f = std::move(f)](){
        return f(&src);  
    })
{ }
```